# Xcode 5.1.1 Auto completion not working

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode5.1

for already created ViewControllers showing auto suggestion but newly creating view controllers not showing auto suggestion please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried quitting Xcode and cleaning your project once?

Comment: Do you mean auto suggestions while doing search or in text field?

Comment: Thanks for your responces, 
@satheeshwaran: Done Xcode quit and restarted MAC also but not solved.

Comment: @Naga Mallesh Maddali: not in text field, suppose if i type ui it has to show uiview uitextfield like this but it is not showing suggestions.

Comment: try http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/bringing-intellisense-back-from-the-dead-xcode/

Comment: @satheeshwaran: tried all the options except moving files to the new project not worked bad luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the Answer, Thanks for your responses.

In my Project under in both Targer and Project i gave this option
BuildSetting -> **Build Active Architecture only - YES**

Now i changed this option  to **Build Active Architecture only - NO**. Now it is working perfectly. Thank you.